# org-mode : how to get more space between 'List of all TODO entries'

Tags: org-mode

`C-a-t` is bound to `org-todo-list (i.e., "List of all TODO entries").

Is there a way to add space between each row in the `*Org Agenda*` output buffer when the list is displayed?

Comment: How about adjusting the line-spacing of the buffer instead of modifying the output of the agenda entries?  Here is a link to a write-up by Xah Lee:  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_toggle_line_spacing.html

Comment: YES!  that works!

Comment: @lawlist do you want to make that into an answer?